# Move EditText from bottom to top and vice-versa when keyboard opens or close with windowSoftInput as adjustNothing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an EditText as a SearchBar that is placed at the bottom of my fragment, and I want to move that EditText to the top when keyboard is in open state, and back to bottom when keyboard closes. I am able to do so when with Keyboardlistener but due to some reasons I want my windowSoftInput as adjustNothing, and with adjust nothing the KeyboardListener does not work. Is there any possible way through which I can achieve this without changing the windowSoftInput mode?

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
                moveSearchBar(isOpen);
            }
        });
private void moveSearchBar(boolean isOpen) {
        Transition changeBounds = new ChangeBounds();
        changeBounds.setDuration(1000);
        changeBounds.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mDiscoverBinding.clDiscover,
                changeBounds);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mDiscoverBinding.clDiscover);
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(mDiscoverBinding.clDiscover);
        if(isOpen) {
            constraintSet.clear(R.id.et_search, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.et_search, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.cl_discover, ConstraintSet.TOP, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dp_16));
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.et_search, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.cl_discover, ConstraintSet.START, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dp_16));
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.et_search, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.cl_discover, ConstraintSet.END, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dp_16));
        } else {
            constraintSet.clear(R.id.et_search, ConstraintSet.TOP);
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.et_search, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.cl_discover, ConstraintSet.START, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dp_16));
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.et_search, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.cl_discover, ConstraintSet.END, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dp_16));
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.et_search, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.cl_discover, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dp_24));
        }
        constraintSet.applyTo(mDiscoverBinding.clDiscover);
    }
```

I am able to move the SearchBar using the above code, but if I change the windowSoftInputMethod to adjustNothing then it does not work, and I need it as adjustNothing for some reasons.

Comment: show your code efforts

Comment: I have updated it, kindly see it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in manifest.

Comment: because of some reasons I have to use it as adjustNothing only, is there any possible way to do it with adjustNothing?